# Xamarin iOS: Will finally be called when expired handler called in background fetch

Tags: ios, xamarin, background-fetch, expirationhandler

If I have a function in PerformFetch to do background fetching in iOS.

I have "finally" statement inside the PerformFetch. When the background fetch expired will the finally block get call as well. 
Or will it go straight to the ExpirationHandler block to do the clean up before the application killed by the OS

Answer (score 0):

When `PerformFetch` (`application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`) is called in the *background* you have ~30 seconds to return from that method or that process will be terminated.

If terminated, your code will never enter the `finally` block with your `PerformFetch` override, nor will `WillTerminate` (`applicationWillTerminate:`) be called. This will be treated by iOS as an `UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed` since `PerformFetch` did not return.

If you flagged the start of some block of code via `BeginBackgroundTask` (`beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:`) within the `PerformFetch` then **yes**, the `expirationHandler` is called when the OS terminates the `PerformFetch`.